# How to uninstall not App Store apps using Launchpad?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, high-sierra, launchpad

Is it possible to make any changes to macOS through the Terminal or in another way, so that Launchpad allows simple uninstalling application files, downloaded not via the App Store?

Comment: No as many apps do not come with uninstallers and there is no standard place they put their files and do you want to delete the documents which might now be unreadable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible but it's a bit "hacky".

1. Open your Applications Directory in Finder
2. Find an app the was installed from the Appstore.
3. Right click on the .app and select Show Package Contents.
4. Copy this directory (_MASReceipt).
   [image: Directory]
5. Now repeat the above steps or write a script to place that directory in 
   all of the non Appstore apps by selecting Show Package Contents and pasting the copied directory.

[image: Without Fix]
[image: With Fix]

Comment: Thank you! The experiment showed that it is not even necessary to copy. It is enough just to create a new folder “_MASReceipt” in folder “Any.app/Contents”, and inside it create an empty file with name “receipt” (without any extension).

Answer (score 0):

Also I just tried doing this and it worked...

Looked up the app in Spotlight, held CMD to show to location of it, then went to the location,

(system drive) > users > (you) > applications

and for some reason was able to delete it from there (:

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  The OP is asking not how to delete the apps in general, but how to configure LaunchPad to allow deletion from there.  Cheers